# ERROR 1067: The Process Terminated Unexpectedly In MySQL Windows Service

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have installed 2 XAMPP in my Local Computer 1st XAMPP with PHP 5.6.40 and 2nd XAMPP with PHP 7.4.1 by following this tutorial  [Starting Multiple MySQL Instances as Windows Services](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-windows-services.html), i named my MySQL service on 1st XAMPP as mysqld1 and on 2nd XAMPP as mysqld2.

I have set my MySQL port on 1st XAMPP with 3308 and the 2nd with 3307.
The 2nd MySQL working beautifully, whereas the 1st MySQL resulting errors
I ran my 1st MySQL Service from Run->service.msg. And then i got following errors:

*Windows could not start the mysqld service on Local Computer.
ERROR 1067: The  Process Terminated Unexpectedly.*:

[The Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvoL5.png).

MySQL on 1st XAMPP was running:

[MySQL on 1st XAMPP was running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YywAY.png).

If i delete ibdata1, ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 while MySQL on 1st XAMPP was turning off, **the mysqld service would start**, but MySQL on 1st XAMPP would give the Following errors instead :

```
14:10:22  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
14:10:22  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:10:22  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:10:22  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:10:22  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:10:22  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
14:10:22  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Vice versa.

I have checked my path either on both of my.ini files or mysqld services path, i think everything is set correctly. And also i have checked for the port (3308) using netstat -an, the port number is listening.

I have searched answers from previous questions here but haven't met the answer yet.

How to solve the issue so i will have 2 XAMPP applications with differ PHP and MySQL versions on my local computer (Laptop) ?

I have no idea how to fix this.

**UPDATE:**

My.ini of MySQL on 1st XAMPP:

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3308
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3308
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

And my.ini of MySQL on 2nd XAMPP :

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# C:/xampp7/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:/xampp7/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3307
socket="C:/xampp7/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3307
socket="C:/xampp7/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="C:/xampp7/mysql"
tmpdir="C:/xampp7/tmp"
datadir="C:/xampp7/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=1M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="C:/xampp7/mysql/lib/plugin/"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "C:/xampp7/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="C:/xampp7/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="C:/xampp7/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp7/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp7/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
```

Comment: Can we see the `my.ini` setting for both services?

Comment: Sure, wait a minute..

Comment: Can the service start individually? Like `mysqld1` start while `mysqld2` stopped or in reverse?

Comment: i can start service either `mysqld1` or `mysqld2` from service.msg. But after started one of those two services, i wouldn't be able to start mysql service from XAMPP-Control Panel, and vice versa.
After start the service i couldn't enter to database with command `mysql -u root` even resulting an error  `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)` , i think the service mysqld1 from service.msg and msyql service from XAMPP must be started to get into the database.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that `xampp` vs `xampp7` folder name.

Comment: Are you able to see the error message in "C:/xampp/mysql/data/xxx.err" file? Is the error message similar to the one you see in xampp?

Comment: i think it's right on the last of message list,

Comment: @tcadidot0 Maybe we couldn't run 2 MySQLs with differ versions in a Local Computer simultaneously in Windows.
I have reinstalled both of my XAMPPs and then run 2 MySQLs with differ versions consecutively.

Comment: Actually you can. I currently have 2 MySQLs (v4 & 8) and 1 MariaDB 10.3 running on my Windows but I didn't install/configure it through XAMPP. Previously I had install 1 MySQL through XAMPP and I don't have any issue running all of them at once.

Comment: so you installed MySQL through XAMPP and next you installed another MySQL or MariaDB  from another app service ?
didn't those ports  crash ?

Comment: No, it didn't crash. I lack experience and knowledge in configuring MySQL through XAMPP so may I ask, is it essential for you to install it through XAMPP? If not, I might be able to help you with an alternate method on how to install MySQL services separately

Comment: Is it reasonable to have server-id = 1 on two servers?

Comment: @tcadidot0 No, it is not. By the way, what is your second app service ? is it wamp ?

Comment: @WilsonHauck i don't know

Comment: @tcadidot0  Please post the results of SELECT @@server-id; from your 4v & v 8 instances.  If they are different, then you have a different situation than 01_secret Lubis_10. (You would not be trying to have a SHARED server-id as he does). Thank you.

Comment: @WilsonHauck its different. MySQL v4 `server-id =0` and MySQL v8 `server-id=1`. However I have another server having two separate MySQL v4 running with both `server-id=0` and everything else is identical except for the datadir and port. But in any of those MySQL v4, I did not explicitly defined the `server-id` nor it was set as default in `my.ini` like the one in MySQL v8. Furthermore I did a little test just now by setting both v4&v8 `server-id=1` and restart the service successfully.

Comment: I haven't test on other version of MySQL though. Maybe v4 is too old and newer version (like 5++ above) has more restriction and because I lack experience in installing through XAMPP, I'm not really sure about the condition. @01_Secret.Lubis_10 , no I didn't install through wamp. I install using the MySQL installer. Once the first MySQL server is configured > I stopped the service > make another copy of the folder > rename it > change necessary things in "my.ini" > install another MySQL service referring to the new folder using command prompt.

Comment: The key is NOT sharing anything from one folder to another. This includes datadir, log files, basedir - etc.  Stopping the service was critical as well before you made the copy to another folder.  If you make icons in Windows ensure START IN is correct folder. Congrats.

Comment: Hmm, now i am running 2 XAMPPs with different versions. I just rename the XAMPP's name (c:\xampp7.4.1) to c:/xampp whenever i want to run the latest PHP and MySQL version and the other to c:/xampp5.6.4 or something else. I was following from this tutorial [Install Multiple XAMPPs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkvKOhJlTFU&t=87s) in 6:55 he said that "_We can't run mysqll simultaneously_".